# Prove that if $T^2$ has a cyclic vector over finite dimensional vector space $V$, then $T$ has a cyclic vector over $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that  if $T^2$ has a cyclic vector over finite dimensional vector space $V$, then $T$ has a cyclic vector over $V$.

Comment: What's a cyclic vector?

Comment: If there exist v in V such that   " v,T(v),........,T^n-1(v)" form basis of V ,then v is said to be cyclic vector .  here  dim V=n.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $span\{ v, T^2v, T^4v, \dots \} \subseteq span\{ v, Tv, T^2v, T^3v, \dots \} $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$T^2v=T(Tv)$$

where $v\in V$ is a [cyclic vector](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Cyclic_vector).